# How to reset the base route in my Flutter App - that is pop any routes and replace it with a new one using Navigator

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator

New to Flutter to please forgive me if this is obvious, but I have read the documentation and tried a bunch of the Navigator options but none of them work as I would like.  The problem set:  We have a complex (well, semi-complex) series of screens, etc. that handle the login / authorization / registration process.  This can get down to 3 or 4 levels on the Route stack.  This is all fine -- no worries.

The problem comes when we get a successful login event (from a few different paths) and want to go to the "home" page.  Once we are on the home page that should be the new "root" of the Route tree (I am sure this isn't the correct terminology -- but I think the idea is solid).

So, given we could be 1/2/3 or even 4 levels down and want to "pop" and replace the whole stack (with any transition events, please) to a new top level root -- what magical Navigator set or methods will do this cleanly?

My current (horrid) approach is to hand "pop()" the levels and do a Navigator.pushReplacementNamed() call (they are all named routes here) but that isn't a generic solution (have to know exactly how many levels) and worse, it causes a "animation" transition to "pop" on the screen for a split second for each pop() which looks .. not very good.

TIA!

Answer (score 54):

Navigator expose more than just `pop`. You can do things such as the following:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/', (_) => false);
```

This will basically push a home and remove *all* the routes behind the new one

Comment: This indeed, worked like a charm!  I had looked at this call but couldn't figure out what the 3rd argument is supposed to be.  Still reading the doc, I am still not sure what the overall purpose is on a "normal" basis for this .. but it works for my purposes!!

Comment: This function decides whether to stop pop or not based on the route details. But in your case you just want to pop everything

Comment: Ah ha!  Well damn -- it's like a magic trick -- once you know how it's done -- it's not a mystery anymore!  Thanks again!

Comment: Be sure to hoist your state objects above your routes (if using Consumer/ChangeNotifierProvider pattern, otherwise your state objects will be disposed.  (learned this the hard way)

Comment: @johnevans do you have an example of state objects "above" the routes?

Comment: @RémiRousselet is not working in my case.

Comment: it's just disabling back pressed, at the place of '/' which route to define or it will be blank.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => YourInitialPage(),
                    ),
                    ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

If you don't want transition you can override or extend the `MaterialPageRoute` class

Answer (score 2):

The good news is now we can use `pushReplacementNamed`

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
```

(Channel master, v1.15.4-pre.97, I'm not sure the previous version can do that)

Comment: Wouldn't that just replace the route on top of the stack?

Comment: @EzPizza you are right, but if you use this method for all links in your navigation/drawer it will achieve the same result :)

Comment: The code does not work as expected when navigating from Screen A to Screen B and then using pushReplacementNamed to reach Screen C. Pressing the back button on the device or a button within the app still navigates back to Screen A, instead of remaining on Screen C to the home screen phone.