# when click back button navigated to every pages I visit

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-navigation

I have 5 screens.

The 5th screen has a button go to the 1st screen.

I clicked the 1st screen and 2nd screen and 3rd screen and 4th screen and 5th screen again clicked the 1st screen and 2nd screen and 3rd screen and 4th screen and 5th screen. (1>2>3>4>5>1>2>3>4>5)

I clicked back button again and again.not stopping in 1st page. go to I visited every page. (5<4<3<2<1<5<4<3<2<1)

I used `WillPopScope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are going from 5th screen to 1st screen, you should not push the 1st screen. Instead, you should use `popUntil` to pop until you get back to 1st screen.

For this, you're going to have to add a [named route](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) to 1st screen, so that you can use something like `ModalRoute.withName('/login')` as shown in the example [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html).

This question seems to be closely related: [Flutter Navigation pop to index 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672706/flutter-navigation-pop-to-index-1)

Comment: You only need to provide a slash if you want to go back to the first item in the stack (e.g., `ModalRoute.withName("/")`)

Comment: I used, Error is coming

Comment: ```[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed```

Comment: @BhanukaIsuru that seems like some other problem with your state code.