# How to pop two screens without using named routing?

Tags: flutter, mobile-application

For example, my current routing is like this:

```
Login -> Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3 -> Screen4
```

I'd like to go back to `Screen2` from `Screen4`.
I can't use named routing, because I have to pass a parameter to `Screen2`.
Push `Screen2` in `Screen4` is not a good solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter Navigation pop to index 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672706/flutter-navigation-pop-to-index-1)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use [`popUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/popUntil.html) method of Navigator class.

e.g.

```dart
int count = 0;
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((_) => count++ >= 2);
```

However, I would recommend defining names for your routes and using `popUntil` as it is designed as per docs.

Answer (score 21):

You can just pop it two times;

```
nav = Navigator.of(context);
nav.pop();
nav.pop();
```

Answer (score 13):

The class from which the transition will be made as StatefulWidget. To press action add the `pushNamed` navigator with `then`, which will trigger after returning to this screen. Pass `setState` to update the widget:

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    RouteNames.viewExercises,
  ).then((value) {
    setState(() {});
  });
},
```

Screen from which to return to be used:

```
Navigator.of(context)
  ..pop()
  ..pop()
  ..pop();
```

where `..pop()` is used as many times as needed to back.

Answer (score 7):

if you would like to pop until three times, You can use the code in below.

```
int count = 3;
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((_) => count-- <= 0);
```

Comment: Is this really different from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56725619/6045800) from 2019?

Comment: .pop()..pop()..pop() 3 times or count++ >=2 makes same effect.  You can use 3 of those solutions depends on your requirement, it's up to you.

Comment: No its not lol.

Answer (score -1):

two lines.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```