# Flutter: How to switch to a page which already is in the Navigator stack?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I have a drawer with named routes to different search pages. Pushing a route navigates to a search page. Each item in a search page navigates to a detail page. The back button pops the detail page and I'm back on the search page. This scenario makes the proper use of the navigator stack.

But how can I switch between multiple search pages?
I can only pop one search page and then push another one.

Another use case I'm looking for is to switch between detail pages. In this case, the Navigator would hold (in this order): first search page, first detail page, second search page, second detail page. I want to switch between the two detail pages.

Is there any way to peek into the Navigator stack and bring the peeked entry to the top of the stack?

Do multiple Navigators help here? Can I switch between Navigators?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navKey = GlobalKey( );

void main( ) => runApp( MyApp( ) );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    final Provider<MyMenu> menuProvider = Provider(
            builder: ( context ) => MyMenu( ) );

    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
        return MultiProvider(
            child: MaterialApp(
                title: 'My App',
                home: MyHomePage( ),
                navigatorKey: navKey,
                routes: {
                    routePage1: ( context ) => Page1( ),
                    routePage2: ( context ) => Page2( ),
                },
                theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue, ),
            ),
            providers: [
                menuProvider,
            ], );
    }
}

class MyMenu extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
        String currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName( );

        return Drawer( child: ListView( children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
                leading: Icon( Icons.home ),
                onTap: ( ) => navigateTo( context, routePage1 ),
                selected: currentRoute == routePage1,
                title: Text( "Page 1" ),
            ),
            ListTile(
                onTap: ( ) => navigateTo( context, routePage1 ),
                selected: currentRoute == routePage1,
                title: Text( "Page 1" ),
            ),
            ListTile(
                onTap: ( ) => navigateTo( context, routePage2 ),
                selected: currentRoute == routePage2,
                title: Text( "Page 2" ),
            ),
        ],
        ),
        );
    }
}

String getCurrentRouteName( ) {
    String currentRouteName;
    navKey.currentState.popUntil( ( route ) {
        currentRouteName = route.settings.name;
        return true;
    } );
    return currentRouteName;
}

void navigateTo( BuildContext context, String namedRoute, { Object arguments } ) {
    // --- Close drawer menu if open
    if ( Scaffold
            .of( context )
            .isDrawerOpen ) {
        navKey.currentState.pop( );
    }

    // --- No navigation if target page already active
    String currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName( );
    if ( currentRoute == namedRoute ) return;

    // --- Navigate to target
    if ( currentRoute == "/" ) {
        navKey.currentState.pushNamed( namedRoute, arguments: arguments );
    } else {
        navKey.currentState.popAndPushNamed( namedRoute, arguments: arguments );
    }
}

class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
        String currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName( );
        return AppBar(
            leading: MenuButton( ),
            title: Text( 'my app -> ${currentRoute}' ), );
    }

    @override
    Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight( kToolbarHeight );
}

class MenuButton extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
        return IconButton(
            icon: Icon( Icons.menu ),
            onPressed: ( ) {
                ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of( context );
                if ( scaffold.isDrawerOpen ) {
                    navKey.currentState.pop( );
                } else {
                    scaffold.openDrawer( );
                }
            },
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: MyAppBar( ),
            body: Center(
                child: Text( "This is the Homepage" ),
            ),
            drawer: Provider.of<MyMenu>( context ),
        );
    }
}

const String routePage1 = '/page1';

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: MyAppBar( ),
            body: Center(
                child: Text( "This is Page 1" ),
            ),
            drawer: Provider.of<MyMenu>( context ),
        );
    }
}

const String routePage2 = '/page2';

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build( BuildContext context ) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: MyAppBar( ),
            body: Center(
                child: Text( "This is Page 2" ),
            ),
            drawer: Provider.of<MyMenu>( context ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling searchPage inside searchPage?

Comment: Code with an answer might helpful.

Comment: I'm calling all searchPages from the Drawer menu with Navigator.pushNamedRoute(). So far the code is standard. I have no code to show my problem because I have no approach for it.

Comment: What do you mean by switch multiple search pages. Can you explain I have solution for you but I don't know what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Did you mean like replacing fragment like drawer in Android.

Comment: I have added a code sample. You can open pages through the central drawer menu. But each page will be pushed on top of the Navigator stack. So opening page1 then page2 will result in the stack: page1 / page2. No opening page 1 again will not reuse the route from the bottom of the stack but will push page1 again resulting in: page1 / page2 / page1 which is weird.

Comment: let me know if this solve your issue.

Comment: A Navigator 2.0 with a Router is under development which will probably solve these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Create a field typed Widget and replace those widgets on menu item like below code.

```
 enum DrawerSelection {
  home,
  cropFamilies,
  cropCalender,
  favorites,
  settings,
  notes,
  contactUs,
  disclaimer
 }

class _MyHomePage extends State<MyHomePage> {

DrawerSelection _drawerSelection = DrawerSelection.home;
Widget _appBarTitle = Text("Home");


Widget _currentWidget = MainWidget();

ListTile(
        selected: _drawerSelection == DrawerSelection.home,
        title: Text('Home'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        onTap: () {
          _drawerSelection = DrawerSelection.home;
          Navigator.pop(context);
          _currentWidget = MainWidget();
          setState(() {
            _appBarTitle = Text("Home");
          });
        },
      ),
  ListTile(
        selected: _drawerSelection == DrawerSelection.cropFamilies,
        title: Text('Crop families فصل کا خاندان'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.nature),
        onTap: () {
          _drawerSelection = DrawerSelection.cropFamilies;
          Navigator.pop(context);
          _currentWidget = CropFamiliesWidget();
          setState(() {
            _appBarTitle = Text("Crop families فصل کا خاندان");
          });
        },
      ),
```

Do this in all your menu items. You can ignore drawer selection if you don't want to show selected color in drawer menu.

**update**
If you want to navigate back in stack to a desired route you can do that with popUntil method like below.[see here](http://https:/https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html)

```
  Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
```

Comment: How does this approach navigate to another page? Are you managing the pages somehow by yourself (without any Navigator)?

Comment: Yes no navigator just replacing widgets after all flutter is all about widgets.

Comment: In my homepage scaffold body I give _currentWidget

Comment: also see these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672706/flutter-navigation-pop-to-index-1

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to do what I asked. The navigator uses an internal stack which cannot be accessed from outside. It does not provide methods like 'boolean containsRoute(route)' and 'extract( route )' which would allow to reuse already created and pushed pages.