# How can I pop to specific screen in flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, uinavigationcontroller

I pushed four screens
 **ScreenOne >> ScreenTwo >> ScreenThree >> ScreenFour**

and I'm at **ScreenFour** now I want to pop back to **ScreenTwo**

In Swift it works like this::

```
if let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
    for vc in viewControllers
    {
        if (vc is SecondViewController)
        {
            self.navigationController!.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

how i perform this operation in flutter.

Please give a solution, **Thank you**.

Comment: follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672706/flutter-navigation-pop-to-index-1

Comment: This may help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672706/flutter-navigation-pop-to-index-1)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you didn't define any route in the MaterialApp then you need to define at the time of push.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return SecondPage();
    },
      settings: RouteSettings(name: 'SecondPage',),
    ));
```

You need to define the same route name

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route){
  return route.settings.name == 'SecondPage';
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use named route then simply use--
***pushAndRemoveUntil***

Example--

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => MyHomePage()), (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that would be the Navigator.popUntil Method.

You need to have your routes defined in your materialApp for Navigator to recognise it. For the code below to work "/home" needs to be defined in my MaterialApp.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'));
```

Answer (score 3):

try `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`,

```
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            '/BottomNavigation', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

For in depth reading follow [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31)

Answer (score 0):

While the `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` might seem like a great idea for unnamed routes, it would give a blank screen if you try to pop any further for pop-capable screen. Unless you're returning to the first screen, it is better to just use the default  `Navigator.pop(context)`