# Pop certain screens and push a screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I pushed(with named routes) few screens like so,

BaseScreen >>(pushNamed) ScreenOne >>(pushNamed) ScreenTwo >>(pushNamed) ScreenThree >>(pushNamed) ScreenFour

While I am at ScreenFour what I wanted was that instead of just pushing ScreenFour to the stack, to remove ScreenThree and ScreenTwo from the stack and then have ScreenFour at top of the stack.

so at the end while im at ScreenFour the stack should look like,

BaseScreen >> ScreenOne >> ScreenFour.

How can I achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay you can do that using `Navigator.pop(context)`, before pushing ScreenFour, use `Navigator.pop` twice. That would do BaseScreen >> ScreenOne >> ScreenFour.

Comment: when I do that it looks a bit ugly in navigation animations though. 
I would have done that but was curious of finding another way to prevent that ugly behaviour

Comment: you can use popUntill too `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/ScreenOne'));`

Comment: tried that and I ended up with a blacked screen though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59223240/11445727 hope this helps

Comment: anyways, I went with the initial answer you provided. it works for the requirement and even though I wanted to find another way with this, im happy for it. Thank you fahmida. ^_^

Comment: I identified primarily that , in my navigation I use a mix of navigation and nested navigation. maybe that caused issues when trying to use popUnitl and pushNamedAndRemoveUntil

Comment: Yes that can be issue. Though maintaining stack is good, otherwise if it is becoming too complex then you can simply use push to the screenone. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil()` for 2nd and 3rd screen and use normal `Navigator.push`  for 4th screen.

Thus it will be possible.

Learn more about *pushAndRemoveUntil* [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

Comment: when I do this it removes all the predicate screens in the stack,

Comment: im doing like this 
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  ScreenFourRouteName, ModalRoute.withName(ScreenOneRouteName));