# How to add a button that redirects or pops to the home page

Tags: flutter

```
class _BottomPart extends StatelessWidget {
  const _BottomPart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
        child: Column(

          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Find The Best Coffee for You',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 27.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Text(
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. '
                  'Nullam pulvinar dolor sed enim eleifend efficitur.',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                height: 1.5,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Container(

                height: 85.0,
                width: 85.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.chevron_right,
                  size: 50.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50.0),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Could you please add more details?

Comment: you can use `Navigator.pop(context)` to go back from a last page, if you want to go to direct home page and remove all the pages  below homepage, then you can use `Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Navigation pop to index 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672706/flutter-navigation-pop-to-index-1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is (assuming that your home is a named route with / as name):

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example of how I go about getting back to the home page and emptying the stack. it is also useful in a disconnection.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: const Text('Log out'), // Go to the HomePage 
      onPressed:(){
        // if you use named routes
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
            "/route/to/homepage", (route) => false,
        );

        // if you don't use named routes
        Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
      }
    );
  }
}
```