# In Flutter, how to properly handle authentication?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, stream-builder

I am using firebase for authentication.
I listen in a StreamBuilder for authStateChanges():

- if user is null, I return LoginPage.
- if user is not null, I show HomePage.
  On HomePage, I can go to AnotherPage by pressing a button, doing Navigator.of(context).push(...). Thing is, if I logout after this, this AnotherPage stays on stack so I have to manually press back to show LoginScreen.

I have tried using Navigator.pop, on logout, but this feels like a hack. What if I have multiple pages on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling the auth correctly.

The issue could be in your navigation there are three possibilities:

**I:** If you are using named routes you can use:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.settings.name == '/home');
```

**II:** If you are using not using named routes:
Check out this answer: [Flutter Navigation pop to index 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672706/flutter-navigation-pop-to-index-1)

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

**/!\** For the two first methods, call these function when detecting a logout action.

**III:** Use a package to help you manage the Navigation

Comment: Im not sure how I did not manage to find this solution, thanks!
What if I would like to have navigator-like animation when the streambuilder would trigger another page?